# how can I force a certain user to log in again asp.net identity

Tags: asp.net, webforms, asp.net-membership

I have a console job running where it will turn the `islockedout` column to 1 in the `[ASPNETDB].[dbo].[aspnet_membership]` table if a user hasn't logged in to the system for 45 days or more.

So when isLockedOut column is set to 1, the user won't be able to log in after that. 
But the problem I have is that when the user originally logged in if they ahd checked the remember me box this allows them to pass the log in page even if islockedout column is set to 1.

Is there a way I can prevent them from logging in?

The biggest problem is I don't have any code to look at .. this is an old web forms page and on there it has this and nothing in code behind...

[image]

Comment: Not that I know of. You can expire all cookies by changing [the name of the Cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792070/expire-all-forms-authentication-cookies). And if there was a method it would require access to the source code.

Comment: Thanks so much! how is this working though? with out any code? how does it know what to execute when log in happens?...

Comment: If you change the name of the cookie in the web.config (always accessible) there is a mismatch and users are sent to the login page.

Comment: no... i mean the log in control... where is the code thats doing all the work related to the log in process? all i have right now is an aspx page with a log in control? is it all just built in? sorry it might be a silly question...

Comment: It is build-in within the aspnet framework. That stuff is all handled for you.