# Allowing access to everyone to a particular page

Tags: asp.net, .net

Restring access to anonymous users but only allow the default.aspx page to be accessed by everyone

the code in my web.config to acheive this is below:

```
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Forms">
  </authentication>
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?"/> 
  </authorization>
</system.web>

<location path="default.aspx">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

However I am still getting error saying `Access Denied` when i go to default.aspx

what am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you navigate to the home of the site, the url is a `/` and not `Default.aspx`. To fix this add the following piece of code to the `Global.asax` file.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath == "~/")
    {
        HttpContext.Current.RewritePath("Default.aspx");
    }
}
```

If you do not have one yet in your project, add it with `Add new item >  Web > Global Application Class`

Comment: thank you so much! Thats excatly what the problem was.

Comment: Could you please take a look at my other question?  Its regarding a login control.. but i dont have any code in the code behind file.. how do i go about solving that when there is no code to look at ? i'm new to web development..

Comment: its here.. if you can take a look at it i really appreciate it.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53752463/how-can-i-force-a-certain-user-to-log-in-again-asp-net-identity

Comment: another question... on this topic... if i set default.aspx as start up page.. it should work the same right? However i am not getting that... i run in to the same issue as before..

Comment: What do you mean by "set as startup page"?

Comment: in the solution explorer i right click on default.aspx and there is an option to "set as start page" there.

Comment: I don't use that. I have a localhost IIS configured. But when I test it, it works as it should. I see the page.

Comment: i set default.aspx as start up page.. then i removed the code you mentioned from the global.asax.cs file (because thats not needed now right since start up is default.aspx) then i still get the access denied error...